# Putting php foreach into single variable comma separated string with white spaces

Tags: php, codeigniter

Putting php foreach into single variable comma separated string with white spaces and special characters.

```
$fruit = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblFruitTrees") 

foreach($fruit as $fruits) {
 $result .= '{"value":"'.$fruits.'"}';
}
```

the output should be:

```
$ result =  {"value":"+red apple"},{"value":"+yellow banana"},{"value":"+green mango"}
```

Comment: XY Problem, use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead.

Comment: it is not working..the white spaces have been replaced with slashes.. @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Your code makes no sense. The first line is ok. Then you loop emails and call them fruits??? When you ask a question here and need to hide real data, at lease make the code make sense. And I believe Lawrence is correct json_encode. Or post data so that your question has some contents

Comment: Can ypu please share how your `$fruit` array looks like? is it: `array("{+red apple}", "{+yellow banana}", "{+green mango}")`? What is your desire output?

Comment: i have already edited my question.@DavidWinder .
@Andreas

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$fruits = array("+red apple", "+yellow banana", "+green mango");
$result = '{"value":"' . implode('"}, {"value":"', $fruits) . '"}';
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
{"value":"+red apple"}, {"value":"+yellow banana"}, {"value":"+green mango"}
```

If the `+` is not actually in the fruits values, just add it to the implode:

```
$fruits = array("red apple", "yellow banana", "green mango");
$result = '{"value":"+' . implode('"}, {"value":"+', $fruits) . '"}';
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
{"value":"+red apple"}, {"value":"+yellow banana"}, {"value":"+green mango"}
```

Here's a solution using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$fruits = array("+red apple", "+yellow banana", "+green mango");
$result = implode(',', array_map(function ($f) { return json_encode(array('value' => $f)); }, $fruits));
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
{"value":"+red apple"},{"value":"+yellow banana"},{"value":"+green mango"}
```

Comment: yes this is what i want but it is not working..it has Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: Why do you invent the wheel and not use `json_encode`?

Comment: @u_mulder See my edit. It doesn't really make OPs particular problem much simpler... If you can figure out an easier way feel free to post...

Comment: it is still not working.. implode(): Invalid arguments passed.. @Nick

Comment: Hi @dain it is working fine for me - see this demo on [Rextester](http://rextester.com/VQQAQ39222)